# Using generics instead of casting for AsEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I am new to generics in C# and while reading a book stumbled upon an example:

```
var cars = from car in data.AsEnumerable()
  where
    car.Field<string>("Color") == "Red"
    select new
    {
      ID = car.Field<int>("CarID"),
      Make = car.Field<string>("Make")
    };
```

The author says that `car.Field<string>("Color")` gives the additional compile-time checking comparing to `(string)car["Color"]`. But how does the compiler know that `car.Field<string>("Color")` is compilable for "Color" and not for "CarID"? Or there is some kind of another "additional compile-time checking" that I miss?

Comment: @DBM, `car` is not an `IEnumerable<T>`, it's `T`.

Comment: Ahh, you're right. I'm tired... T could be a `DataRow`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't give you any additional compile-time checking. If you use the wrong type, in both cases you'll get an exception during run-time.

But it can be useful to do additional stuff that simple cast can't. For example `Field<int>("CarId")` could call a method that converts the `string` in the field to an `int`.

And assuming you're talking about [`DataRow.Field<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx), then, according to the documentation, it's useful mostly for dealing with `null` values and nullable types correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't know, your specifying that field "Color" is of type string. Internally, the `Field<T>()` method does it's magic to make that happen.

If you perform a cast (`(string)car["Color"]`) you could encounter a runtime exception if the field value cannot be converted to the destination type.

From memory, if you specify `car.Field<string>("ColorID")`, you will be able to safely convert int to string without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, the real benefit of `car.Field<string>("Color")` is that it encapsulates testing field values for equality with `DBNull.Value`, making your code cleaner and easier to read.

In your example, if the value of the "Color" field is null, the `Field<T>` extension method will return `null`, while `car["Color"]` will return `DBNull.Value`.  You can't cast `DBNull.Value` to `string`, so the expression `(string)car["Color"]` raises an `InvalidCastException` in that case.

Before the development of the `DataSetExtensions` class, you would need a somewhat verbose expression to assign the value of that field to a `string` variable:

```
var color = DBNull.Value.Equals(car["Color"]) ? null : (string)car["Color"];
```

Another benefit of `Field<T>` is, as svick notes, that it enables you to work with nullable types and reference types using the same syntax.